# Setting number format for a column as percentage using SpreadsheetGear

Tags: formatting, excel-formula, excel-2010, spreadsheetgear

I am using SpreadsheetGear and I want to set format for a column as %. currently I am using following code:

```
 worksheet.Cells[0, index].EntireColumn.NumberFormat = @"##0.00\%;[Red](##0.00\%)";
```

The above code apply formatting which converts:
6 =    6.00%
6.02 = 6.02%
.02 =  .02%

But the problem is when I use this value and perform a math operation, excel consider actual value. Example: if a cell is showing 20.00% and I multiply it with 10 it gives me 200.00.

**What I want is**: When any numeric operation is performed & column type is defined as % system should divide the value by 100 and then it should perform the opeartion.

so if I multiple 24.00% with 10 it should give me .24.

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting format for a column as % in Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17698345/setting-format-for-a-column-as-in-excel)

Answer (score 2):

If you escape the % (\%), Excel just adds the % and does not adjust the decimal. For example, the following code

```
//with escape
cells[0, 0].NumberFormat = @"##0.00\%;[Red](##0.00\%)";
cells[0, 0].Value = 0.24;
//with no escape
cells[1, 0].NumberFormat = @"##0.00%;[Red](##0.00)%";
cells[1, 0].Value = 0.24;
//with no formatting
cells[2, 0].Value = 0.24;

cells[0, 1].FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]*100";
cells[1, 1].FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]*100";
cells[2, 1].FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]*100";
```

will produce

```
0.24%   24 //with escape
24.00%  24 //with no escape
0.24    24 //with no formatting
```

Comment: Thank you for great reply. Your solution solves half of the proble.While it performs correct calculation, but If I don't escape the % symbol it shows .24 as 24.00% which I dont want.

Comment: How do you want .24 displayed?

Comment: i want to show 24 as 24.00% but when a multiplication operation is performed, it should multiply by 0.24 . so if column a1 = 24.00% and b1 = 10 and i multiply A1*B1 it should give me 2.4 (.24*10)

Comment: You cannot change the value by formatting. If you use 0.24 as your value, the above code should do what you are describing. 0.24 equals 24.00%. If you use 24 as your value, it doesn't make sense. You cannot multiply 24 by 10 and get 2.4.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. I know it does not make much sense. But thats what I have been asked to do. Can you please suggest and work around.

Comment: You could add a hidden column that divides the value by 100 to give you the correct percentage value.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is a math problem.

24% x 10 = 240%

240% = 2.4

"so if I multiple 24.00% with 10 it should give me .24"

If all you are trying to do is show a different output, then the system should interpret multiplying by 10 as removing the % formatting. This is because 24% and .24 are the same numbers. You are basically asking the machine to do multiplication incorrectly. Which is fine if that is what your client really really wants.